# Validate password only using Parse in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is there a way to verify just a password in the JavaScript version of Parse?

I would like to only validate if a password is correct without logging in the user. The documentation of Parse only shows a login method to validate the password.

I have access to all the user information necessary for this operation.

Comment: its just a string you can do with it whatever you want

Comment: yes, but i want to know if is there a parse method that takes the password without doing parse login, i will edit the question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no method built in, and the passwords are very protected. It would be an absurdly poor choice to try to access a user's password yourself to do this, if you even could.

Why doesn't the login function suit your needs? You could just not do anything in the success handler, or immediately log out in the success handler.

Comment: hi! i ended up choosing to login and immediately logout. It was really not a good choice my previous one of the question. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad you got sorted.